# Wrong repository - Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, nexus

I'm trying to configure some dependencies in a Java project using Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.basho.riak</groupId>
        <artifactId>riak-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

They are not being recognised using IntellIJ so I've tried running this from console:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

It didn't work but I've managed to see that Maven is looking for the dependencies at the private Nexus of my Company (totally unrelated). So, I guess my Maven was configured to search in this repo instead of the public ones maybe? How can I change this configuration to get this dependencies correctly?

I'm using macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Look in `~/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ok, I have looked and you are right, here is the url to the nexus of my company, encapsulated as a ```mirror```. How can I reset it to look for dependencies at the default repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a bit peculiar about configuration which typically happen for everything in `~/.m2/settings.xml`.  Unfortunately the XML-language is not smart enough to include actual code which mean that you cannot set things conditionally like "Use this mirror when I'm on a company network" (which you appear to have done earlier).

You can, however, rename it to for example `~/.m2/company-settings.xml` for now, so Maven will use its built-in defaults, and rename it back when you need the current functionality again.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ mvn install -s /path/to/my-settings.xml
```

use specific settings xml file can make you skip your company's private repo.